# Is it possible to check if a tomcat server is running in port 8080 using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, mysql, tomcat, port

I have to display tomcat and mysql running status in jsp page.. If tomcat and mysql is down, i have to display as "Down".. When i use java's

```
try {
URL url = new URL(protocol, host, port, "");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

connection.connect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    isAlive = false;
}
```

Its taking too much time to load the jsp with status.. So i planned to check tomcat status with jquery.. Is it possible ? Or what way can i accomplish it.

Comment: How can you run a jsp page if Tomcat is down?

Comment: @jrummell maybe he has two servers, one that acts as proxy and one that is actually doing the work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call some site on that server via ajax in jquery:

```
  $.get("some_site_url")
    .success(function() { alert("server is working"); })
    .error(function() { alert("server is not working"); });
```